# Caching URL - Creating appropriate NSString representation

Tags: cocoa, url, caching, hash, nsstring

I want to cache an image I download from a URL in the local filesystem.

What I don't know, is how can I create from the URL a `NSString` that is compatible with the characters the iOS file system supports. For instance, if I try to create a file with a `:` in the name, it will fail.

What steps should I follow to create this `NSString`? Is a simple hash the best way to go? If so, what hash routine is available in iOS that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use hashing:

- it'll make for much more readable file names
- you avoid problems with file name length

md5 should be perfectly fine for your purposes. Unfortunately, the ios5-sdk contains only a C-String function for this:

```
CC_MD5(in, in_len, out);
```

The function is contained in `<CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>`, there are other hash functions there, too.

You can find infos on how to wrap this up in a function that takes/returns an NSString [here](http://letsiphone.posterous.com/md5-hash-on-iphone).

Answer (score 0):

The following code belongs to ZDS_Shared. `resolveLocalURLForRemoteURL` accepts a remote URL and returns a URL pointing to the file on the iOS filesystem. The filename will be an alphanumeric string that doesn't resemble the original URL, but that shouldn't be a problem.

https://github.com/ZarraStudios/ZDS_Shared/blob/master/ZSAssetManager.m#L185

```
- (NSURL*)resolveLocalURLForRemoteURL:(NSURL*)url
{
  if (!url) return nil;

  NSString *filename = [[url absoluteString] zs_digest];
  NSString *filePath = [[self cachePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

  return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
}
```

https://github.com/ZarraStudios/ZDS_Shared/blob/master/NSString%2BZSAdditions.m#L38

```
// NSString category
- (NSString*)zs_digest
{
  const char *cstr = [self cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
  return [[NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:strlen(cstr)] zs_digest];
}
```

https://github.com/ZarraStudios/ZDS_Shared/blob/master/NSData%2BZSAdditions.m#L38

```
// NSData category
- (NSString*)zs_digest
{
  uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

  CC_SHA1([self bytes], [self length], digest);

  NSMutableString* outputHolder = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

  for (int i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
    [outputHolder appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
  }

  NSString *output = [outputHolder copy];
  MCRelease(outputHolder);

  return [output autorelease];
}
```